# Undefined on tohere and fromhere message windows in google maps API V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map loading on my site (I am not a java coder this is code i have found on the internet). I have figured out mostly how to get it working for my needs. However when you click on the To Here or From Here links instead of populating the address from the marker over it shows as undefined in the message window. I am sure this is something easy I am missing but any help is appreciated

```
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
// arrays to hold copies of the markers and html used by the side_bar 
// because the function closure trick doesnt work there 
var gmarkers = [];
var htmls = [];

// arrays to hold variants of the info window html with get direction forms open
var to_htmls = [];
var from_htmls = [];

// global "map" variable
var map = null;

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    size: new google.maps.Size(150, 50)
});


function initialize() {

    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(33.3440017700195, -111.96068572998);

    var mapOptions = {
        center: location,
        zoom: 14,
        scrollwheel: true
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
        mapOptions);

    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("map"));
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.close();
    });

    var image = {
        url: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/green.png'
    };
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(33.34396, -111.960606),
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        icon: image,
        Title: 'Fusion Formulations<br>1430 W Auto Drive<br>Tempe, AZ 85284'
    });

    var i = gmarkers.length;
    latlng = location;

    // The info window version with the "to here" form open
    to_htmls[i] = html +
        '<b>To here<\/b> - <a href="javascript:fromhere(' + i + ')">From here<\/a>' +
        '<br>Start address:<form action="javascript:getDirections()">' +
        '<input type="text" SIZE=40 MAXLENGTH=40 name="saddr" id="saddr" value="" /><br>' +
        '<INPUT value="Get Directions" TYPE="button" onclick="getDirections()"><br>' +
        'Walk <input type="checkbox" name="walk" id="walk" /> &nbsp; Avoid Highways <input type="checkbox" name="highways" id="highways" />' +
        '<input type="hidden" id="daddr" value="' + latlng.lat() + ',' + latlng.lng() +
        '"/>';
    // The info window version with the "from here" form open
    from_htmls[i] = html + '<br>Directions: <a href="javascript:tohere(' + i + ')">To here<\/a> - <b>From here<\/b>' +
        '<br>End address:<form action="javascript:getDirections()">' +
        '<input type="text" SIZE=40 MAXLENGTH=40 name="daddr" id="daddr" value="" /><br>' +
        '<INPUT value="Get Directions" TYPE="SUBMIT"><br>' +
        'Walk <input type="checkbox" name="walk" id="walk" /> &nbsp; Avoid Highways <input type="checkbox" name="highways" id="highways" />' +
        '<input type="hidden" id="saddr" value="' + latlng.lat() + ',' + latlng.lng() +
        '"/>';
    // The inactive version of the direction info
    var html = marker.getTitle() + '<br>Directions: <a href="javascript:tohere(' + i + ')">To here<\/a> - <a href="javascript:fromhere(' + i + ')">From here<\/a>';
    var contentString = html;

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        map.setZoom(15);
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
        infowindow.setContent(contentString);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    // save the info we need to use later for the side_bar
    gmarkers.push(marker);
    htmls[i] = html;
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

// ===== request the directions =====
function getDirections() {
    // ==== Set up the walk and avoid highways options ====
    var request = {};
    if (document.getElementById("walk").checked) {
        request.travelMode = google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING;
    } else {
        request.travelMode = google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING;
    }

    if (document.getElementById("highways").checked) {
        request.avoidHighways = true;
    }
    // ==== set the start and end locations ====
    var saddr = document.getElementById("saddr").value;
    var daddr = document.getElementById("daddr").value;

    request.origin = saddr;
    request.destination = daddr;
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        } else alert("Directions not found:" + status);
    });
}


// This function picks up the click and opens the corresponding info window
function myclick(i) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
}


// functions that open the directions forms
function tohere(i) {
    //gmarkers[i].openInfoWindowHtml(to_htmls[i]);
    infowindow.setContent(to_htmls[i]);
    infowindow.open(map, gmarkers[i]);
}

function fromhere(i) {
    //gmarkers[i].openInfoWindowHtml(from_htmls[i]);
    infowindow.setContent(from_htmls[i]);
    infowindow.open(map, gmarkers[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You aren't defining the `html` variable which is used for that first field of the HTML in the infowindow.

```
// The info window version with the "to here" form open
to_htmls[i] = html +
  '<b>To here<\/b> - <a href="javascript:fromhere(' + i + ')">From here<\/a>' +
// ...
  '"/>';
```

That should be the HTML you want displayed, in the case or your example, this works for me:

```
html = 'Fusion Formulations<br>1430 W Auto Drive<br>Tempe, AZ 85284<br>';
```

Also, you have an issue with the `title` property of the marker.  You are assigning the `Title` property, which is not the same (javascript is case sensitive).

(Also, FYI, the [MarkerOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions) title property doesn't support HTML markup, so you shouldn't include HTML markup in the title string)

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/fwz69a56/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
// arrays to hold copies of the markers and html used by the side_bar 
// because the function closure trick doesnt work there 
var gmarkers = [];
var htmls = [];

// arrays to hold variants of the info window html with get direction forms open
var to_htmls = [];
var from_htmls = [];

// global "map" variable
var map = null;

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  size: new google.maps.Size(150, 50)
});


function initialize() {

  var location = new google.maps.LatLng(33.3440017700195, -111.96068572998);

  var mapOptions = {
    center: location,
    zoom: 14,
    scrollwheel: true
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
    mapOptions);

  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("map"));
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.close();
  });

  var image = {
    url: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/green.png'
  };
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(33.34396, -111.960606),
    map: map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    icon: image,
    Title: 'Fusion Formulations<br>1430 W Auto Drive<br>Tempe, AZ 85284'
  });
  html = 'Fusion Formulations<br>1430 W Auto Drive<br>Tempe, AZ 85284<br>';
  var i = gmarkers.length;
  latlng = location;

  // The info window version with the "to here" form open
  to_htmls[i] = html +
    '<b>To here<\/b> - <a href="javascript:fromhere(' + i + ')">From here<\/a>' +
    '<br>Start address:<form action="javascript:getDirections()">' +
    '<input type="text" SIZE=40 MAXLENGTH=40 name="saddr" id="saddr" value="" /><br>' +
    '<INPUT value="Get Directions" TYPE="button" onclick="getDirections()"><br>' +
    'Walk <input type="checkbox" name="walk" id="walk" /> &nbsp; Avoid Highways <input type="checkbox" name="highways" id="highways" />' +
    '<input type="hidden" id="daddr" value="' + latlng.lat() + ',' + latlng.lng() +
    '"/>';
  // The info window version with the "from here" form open
  from_htmls[i] = html + '<a href="javascript:tohere(' + i + ')">To here<\/a> - <b>From here<\/b>' +
    '<br>End address:<form action="javascript:getDirections()">' +
    '<input type="text" SIZE=40 MAXLENGTH=40 name="daddr" id="daddr" value="" /><br>' +
    '<INPUT value="Get Directions" TYPE="SUBMIT"><br>' +
    'Walk <input type="checkbox" name="walk" id="walk" /> &nbsp; Avoid Highways <input type="checkbox" name="highways" id="highways" />' +
    '<input type="hidden" id="saddr" value="' + latlng.lat() + ',' + latlng.lng() +
    '"/>';
  // The inactive version of the direction info
  var html = marker.getTitle() + '<br>Directions: <a href="javascript:tohere(' + i + ')">To here<\/a> - <a href="javascript:fromhere(' + i + ')">From here<\/a>';
  var contentString = html;

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    map.setZoom(15);
    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  // save the info we need to use later for the side_bar
  gmarkers.push(marker);
  htmls[i] = html;
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

// ===== request the directions =====
function getDirections() {
  // ==== Set up the walk and avoid highways options ====
  var request = {};
  if (document.getElementById("walk").checked) {
    request.travelMode = google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING;
  } else {
    request.travelMode = google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING;
  }

  if (document.getElementById("highways").checked) {
    request.avoidHighways = true;
  }
  // ==== set the start and end locations ====
  var saddr = document.getElementById("saddr").value;
  var daddr = document.getElementById("daddr").value;

  request.origin = saddr;
  request.destination = daddr;
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else alert("Directions not found:" + status);
  });
}


// This function picks up the click and opens the corresponding info window
function myclick(i) {
  google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
}


// functions that open the directions forms
function tohere(i) {
  //gmarkers[i].openInfoWindowHtml(to_htmls[i]);
  infowindow.setContent(to_htmls[i]);
  infowindow.open(map, gmarkers[i]);
}

function fromhere(i) {
  //gmarkers[i].openInfoWindowHtml(from_htmls[i]);
  infowindow.setContent(from_htmls[i]);
  infowindow.open(map, gmarkers[i]);
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

(note the actual directions request doesn't work in the code snippet due to a security restriction: `Blocked form submission to 'javascript:getDirections()' because the form's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-forms' permission is not set.`, it does work in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/fwz69a56/1/))

Comment: This fixed all of my issues, you are the best thank you sir.

Comment: If this answered your question/fixed your issue, please [accept it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)